# Laravel get all data from database and put it into a chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-4, charts

I'm working with **Laravel 4** to build an applicaton.

Now, I do count all my visitors in a 'unique' way. So the system does chack if there was already a visit this day and if so, it just counts a click in the database.

> What my database structure look like:

[image: Structure]

I want the system to count the visitors (so the IP adressess) of day X in month X. Like the visitors of `30/04/2015` wich is in my table `2015-04-30`. I want to count all the IP adressess of that day and the other days of a month. But when the month is over, it needs to get the values of the next month, so I want the values of the current month.

The `hits` are just to count the 'clicks' on my site, so don't need to mention that.

The date and visit_date give me the current date of visiting and visit_time gives me the time of the visit.

My current code looks like this to display the values:

```
public function index()
{

    $select_stats = DB::table('visitor')->whereBetween('visit_date', array(date('Y-m-01'), date('Y-m-t')))->get();

    $month = date('m');

    $get_count = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT count(*) FROM visitor WHERE MONTH(date) = $month GROUP BY DAY(date)"));


    foreach($select_stats as $statics) {

   //change our object to an array
   $statics = array();
    }


return View::make('admin.home.index')->with('stats', $select_stats)/*->with('count', $get_count)*/;

}
```

But When I try to display this code, with the counted numbers, it doesn't work anymore. My view looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var visitors = [
@foreach($stats as $stat)
                ['{{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($stat->date)) }}', 55],
@endforeach
            ];
</script>
```

So the `55` inside of my view are the counted visitors as output.

Could someone help me as soon as possible please?

Kindest regards,

Robin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding all that well, but a few things that could help... 1. I'd really suggest looking into using model classes in stead of using DB raw queries.  Thats where Laravel is really great. For example it would be:

```
$select_stats= Visitor::where('visit_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get();
$get_count = $select_stats->count();
```

2. In stead of doing a foreach in the script, I'd return a json array. So you could send the 'stats' variable to your view instead as:

   with('stats', $select_stats->lists('visit_date'))

and then in the script you'd just have to use:

```
{{ json_encode($stats) }}
```

Comment: I don't understand this... Could you maybe explain it a bit more? What must there stand in the Model? What does my view look like than? How does my controller work/look like?

Comment: I tried to implementate the code, the output I've got from a little edit is this: `var visitors = [{"21":"2015-05-01","51":"2015-05-01"}];
` The problem is, the time needs to be displayed as another format and it needs to be first the time, then the count. Also my controller looks like this: http://laravel.io/bin/RE6mX Hope you can help me out and let it count the number of IP-adressess per day. Thanks!

Comment: The loop is must be something like this also: `['1/05/2015', 80]` So the date and then the count of the IP-adressess that day. It needs to loop that, not everything inside an array. So: `['1/05/2015', 80], ['2/05/2015', 852]` etc...